# Set a Scrollable date and time picker in Android

Tags: java, android, date, time, calendar

I want to make date time picker in my activity which should be scrollable not clickable means the one like titanium in Iphone. So i tried to use Date time picker but didn't work. So if any one has idea or any link of source code please help. Help Appreciated.

Comment: do you want same as iphone date picker view ?

Comment: no but it should be scrollable on touch not by click

Comment: You can also search in internet "Android Custom Date Time Picker Example."

Comment: i thought i did, i didn't find one. all i could find were link to those stupid clickble pickers. now please don't say that you didn't search enough. Because its really easy to say that google this or google that. So if you find than please post the link as comment i will surly accept your answer and up vote it. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can search as drum picker or date slider for android in google.

anyway check this link

https://github.com/sys1yagi/AndroidPractice/tree/master/DrumPicker/trunk